# Why is my .Net 5 custom attribute instantiated twice?

Tags: asp.net-core, attributes, .net-5

I have a custom attribute on a .Net 5 API controller method. When I call my method (or any other method in my controller for that matter) it calls the constructor of my attribute twice.

If I request again the same method it doesn't run at all so I guess the controller is a singleton?

```
[HttpGet]
[MyCustomAttribute(stringthing, enumthing)]
public IActionResult Get(){
    ...
}
```

And the attribute

```
internal class MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    const string POLICY_PREFIX = "MinimumAge";

    public MinimumAgeAuthorizeAttribute(int age) => Age = age;

    // Get or set the Age property by manipulating the underlying Policy property
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            if (int.TryParse(Policy.Substring(POLICY_PREFIX.Length), out var age))
            {
                return age;
            }
            return default(int);
        }
        set
        {
            Policy = $"{POLICY_PREFIX}{value.ToString()}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `MyCustomAttribute`?

Comment: Edited to show attribute